# React js Reduce method is calculation only the first two values and returns NAN

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a value from a nested object and trying to get the summation.
below i have added my code block.. This calculates the first two values from the nested object and returns a NAN for the third one.. what i am i doing wrong here?

Note: i am getting the percentage and using it to get the value of the quantity within the map.

```
 {data[zone][product]
  .map(
    (dt, j) =>
    (dt.order_list[0].order_list_products[j].mix_percentage / 100) *
  dt.tons_ordered,
  )
  .reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.tr}>
      {Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue)}
      {console.log(Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue))}
    </Text>
  )
})}
```

Comment: You are returnning `<Text>...</Text>` so `previousValue` will be `<Text>....</Text>`

Comment: @Konrad I have posted an answer below that gives me a value of 0 without the Text tag

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issues below is my code block. @konrad thank you for pointing out the return

```
{data[zone][product]
                            .map(
                              (dt, j) =>
                                (dt.order_list[0].order_list_products[j].mix_percentage / 100) *
                                dt.tons_ordered,
                            )
                            .reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
                              return Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue)
                            }, 0)
                            .toFixed(3)}
```